# R output from glmer() - Which settings are required to make it match Stata output?

Tags: r, stata, lme4-nlme

Since this is a setting question, I'm omitting a data file and my exact variable names.  When I run:

```
library(lme4) 

fit <- glmer(Y~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + (1 | x5), 
data=df, family = binomial, glmerControl(optimizer = "nloptwrap",
calc.derivs = FALSE))
```

My results in R are close, but do not exactly match the results of XTLOGIT in Stata with the same variables (and from a different analyst).  Some odds ratios are off by very minor amounts (e.g. 0.88 vs. 0.89), and the standard errors are a little different (a couple items marginally significant in R, e.g. p=0.046 vs. p=0.054).  My guess is this has to do with the user of different optimizers and settings from glmerControl, but I couldn't find information on this without ordering a Stata book (and that might not even help).  Any ideas for which settings to use so that the results are more identical?

Comment: Stata is probably using a small-sample adjustment to the standard errors. There are several threads on SO where this has come up. It's hard to know since you don't show the Stata code that you want to emulate. There's also ample documentation on Stata. Here's the entry for [`xtlogit`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155638/clustered-standard-errors-in-r-using-plm-with-fixed-effects/33160294#33160294) that contains options, examples, and formulas.

Comment: Even when there's no clustering?  I'm aware of the issue in your link, I use that same correction when clustering SEs.  Here I'm interested primarily in the optimization algorithm that Stata uses for maximum likelihood, which I haven't been able to locate online.  The parameter is user-defined in R so I can then match.  This is also a large sample (n>50k)

Comment: I believe Stata uses (N/N-k) even where there's no clustering. I got the documentation link wrong. Here's [the right one](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/xtxtlogit.pdf) that has descriptions of the defaults maximization algos.